# Margin Basics on Form: Trying to align label and text area elements?

Tags: html, css, forms, webforms, margin

Okay, the problem seems to be relatively simple.

**Problem:** I'm trying to align the label message element and the text area element side by side just like other input fields.

Here is a screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/e52hU.jpg

I know I can possibly use absolute positioning but I know something is wrong with my margins perhaps I don't know what. Any ideas please?

```css
    footer {
     background-color: #2094d0;
    }
    .contact-us-section h3 {
    
    }
    footer label {
     color: #fff;
     padding: 1em;
     margin-left: 1%;
    
    }
    
    footer input {
     margin: 2%;
     border-style: none;
     padding: 2%;
    }
    
    footer fieldset {
     border-style: none; 
    }
    
    footer textarea {
     border: none;
     margin-top: 1%;
     margin-left: 28%;
     margin-right: 0;
    
     background-color: black;
    }
    
    footer #message-label {
     background-color:orange;
    
    }
```

```html
 <footer>
  <div class="contact-us-section">
   <h3> CONTACT US</h3>
   <form action="#">
    <fieldset>
     <label>Name:</label></form>
     <input type="text" value="name"><br> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <label>Email:</label>
     <input type="text" value="email"><br>     
    </fieldset>
     <label id="message-label">Message:</label>
     <textarea rows="10" cols="39" maxlength="200"></textarea></br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">     
   </form>
  </div>
  <div class="location">
   <!-- map icon -->
   <img src="img/map-icon.png">
   <p>25/153 Queens st, Avenue, Brisbane, QLD 4000</p>

   <!-- map image -->
   <img src="img/map.png"> 
  </div>
  <div class="social-wrapper">
   <!-- Social icons -->
   <img src="img/instagram-icon.png">
   <img src="img/twitter-icon.png">
   <img src="img/fb-icon.png">
   
  </div>

  <p> KEEVA INC © 2017 </p>

 </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below css or use `vertical-align:middle` to  `footer textarea` to get it.

```
.box {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Changes in css

```
footer textarea {
      border: none;
      /*margin-top: 1%;*/ 
      margin-left: 1%;
      margin-right: 0;
      background-color: black;
      color:#fff;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <label id="message-label">Message:</label>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="39" maxlength="200"></textarea></br>
</div>
```

```css
footer {
  background-color: #2094d0;
}

.contact-us-section h3 {}

footer label {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

footer input {
  margin: 2%;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 2%;
}

footer fieldset {
  border-style: none;
}

.box {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
}

footer textarea {
  border: none;
  /*margin-top: 1%;*/ 
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color:#fff;
}

footer #message-label {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="contact-us-section">
    <h3> CONTACT US</h3>
    <form action="#">
      <fieldset>
        <label>Name:</label></form>
    <input type="text" value="name"><br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="text" value="email"><br>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="box">
      <label id="message-label">Message:</label>
      <textarea rows="10" cols="39" maxlength="200"></textarea></br>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="location">
    <!-- map icon -->
    <img src="img/map-icon.png">
    <p>25/153 Queens st, Avenue, Brisbane, QLD 4000</p>

    <!-- map image -->
    <img src="img/map.png">
  </div>
  <div class="social-wrapper">
    <!-- Social icons -->
    <img src="img/instagram-icon.png">
    <img src="img/twitter-icon.png">
    <img src="img/fb-icon.png">

  </div>

  <p> KEEVA INC © 2017 </p>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is an example how to solve the alignment of textarea with the other labels: (you need to use vertical-align: middle;)

```css
footer {
     background-color: #2094d0;
    }
    .contact-us-section h3 {
    
    }
    

    footer label {
     color: #fff;
     padding: 1em;
     margin-left: 1%;
    
    }
    
    footer input {
     margin: 2%;
     border-style: none;
     padding: 2%;
    }
    
    footer fieldset {
     border-style: none; 
    }
    
    footer textarea {
     border: none;

     border-style: none;
      vertical-align: middle;
    
     background-color: black;
    }
    
    footer #message-label {
     background-color:orange;
    
    }
```

```html
  
 <footer>
  <div class="contact-us-section">
   <h3> CONTACT US</h3>
   <form  action="#">
    <fieldset>
     <label>Name:</label></form>
     <input type="text" value="name"/><br> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input id="email" type="text" value="email"/><br>     
    </fieldset>
        <fieldset >
     <label for="textarea" >Message:</label>
     <textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="39" maxlength="200"></textarea></br>
        </fieldset> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">     
   </form>
  </div>
  <div class="location">
   <!-- map icon -->
   <img src="img/map-icon.png">
   <p>25/153 Queens st, Avenue, Brisbane, QLD 4000</p>

   <!-- map image -->
   <img src="img/map.png"> 
  </div>
  <div class="social-wrapper">
   <!-- Social icons -->
   <img src="img/instagram-icon.png">
   <img src="img/twitter-icon.png">
   <img src="img/fb-icon.png">
   
  </div>

  <p> KEEVA INC © 2017 </p>

 </footer>
```

```css
    footer {
     background-color: #2094d0;
    }
    .contact-us-section h3 {
    
    }
    footer label {
     color: #fff;
     padding: 1em;
     margin-left: 1%;
    
    }
    
    footer input {
     margin: 2%;
     border-style: none;
     padding: 2%;
    }
    
    footer fieldset {
     border-style: none; 
    }
    
    footer textarea {
     border: none;
     margin-top: 1%;
     margin-left: 28%;
     margin-right: 0;
    
     background-color: black;
    }
    
    footer #message-label {
     background-color:orange;
    
    }
```

```html
 <footer>
  <div class="contact-us-section">
   <h3> CONTACT US</h3>
   <form action="#">
    <fieldset>
     <label>Name:</label></form>
     <input type="text" value="name"><br> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <label>Email:</label>
     <input type="text" value="email"><br>     
    </fieldset>
     <label id="message-label">Message:</label>
     <textarea rows="10" cols="39" maxlength="200"></textarea></br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">     
   </form>
  </div>
  <div class="location">
   <!-- map icon -->
   <img src="img/map-icon.png">
   <p>25/153 Queens st, Avenue, Brisbane, QLD 4000</p>

   <!-- map image -->
   <img src="img/map.png"> 
  </div>
  <div class="social-wrapper">
   <!-- Social icons -->
   <img src="img/instagram-icon.png">
   <img src="img/twitter-icon.png">
   <img src="img/fb-icon.png">
   
  </div>

  <p> KEEVA INC © 2017 </p>

 </footer>
```